# nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, nullable, invalidoperationexception

There is paradox in the exception description:
Nullable object must have a value (?!)

This is the problem:

I have a `DateTimeExtended` class, 
that has

```
{
  DateTime? MyDataTime;
  int? otherdata;

}
```

and a constructor

```
DateTimeExtended(DateTimeExtended myNewDT)
{
   this.MyDateTime = myNewDT.MyDateTime.Value;
   this.otherdata = myNewDT.otherdata;
}
```

running this code

```
DateTimeExtended res = new DateTimeExtended(oldDTE);
```

throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the message:

> Nullable object must have a value.

`myNewDT.MyDateTime.Value` - is valid and contain a regular `DateTime` object.

What is the meaning of this message and what am I doing wrong?

Note that `oldDTE` is not `null`. I've removed the `Value` from `myNewDT.MyDateTime` but the same exception is thrown due to a generated setter.

Comment: What is the other constructor?

Comment: Strange. I reproduce the exception with the .Value there, and get no exception without the .Value there. Are you sure you're running the updated code?

Comment: The constructor takes an instance of itself. how are you creating that first instance?

Comment: it is constructed as new() without parameters, and then I add the values (it works).

Comment: @Yuliy - I get the same exception if I try to set the otherdata field first.

Comment: @Yuliy - I've run this code in a new project and it works as you said. I'm trying to figure out what went wrong....

Comment: Problem solved - the problem wasn't there... there was a generated setter to the otherdata and MyDateTime, that was checking the value before setting it.. flying when it's null !!!

Comment: yes, the same problem i had, its only because i had null able object,

Answer (score 264, accepted):

You should change the line `this.MyDateTime = myNewDT.MyDateTime.Value;` to just `this.MyDateTime = myNewDT.MyDateTime;`

The exception you were receiving was thrown in the **`.Value`** property of the **Nullable** `DateTime`, as it is required to return a `DateTime` (since that's what the contract for `.Value` states), but it can't do so because there's no `DateTime` to return, so it throws an exception.

In general, it is a bad idea to blindly call `.Value` on a nullable type, unless you have some prior knowledge that that variable **MUST** contain a value (i.e. through a **`.HasValue`** check).

**EDIT**

Here's the code for `DateTimeExtended` that does not throw an exception:

```
class DateTimeExtended
{
    public DateTime? MyDateTime;
    public int? otherdata;

    public DateTimeExtended() { }

    public DateTimeExtended(DateTimeExtended other)
    {
        this.MyDateTime = other.MyDateTime;
        this.otherdata = other.otherdata;
    }
}
```

I tested it like this:

```
DateTimeExtended dt1 = new DateTimeExtended();
DateTimeExtended dt2 = new DateTimeExtended(dt1);
```

Adding the `.Value` on `other.MyDateTime` causes an exception. Removing it gets rid of the exception. I think you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: You are right about the .value, yet something else causes the exception.
I've removed the .value, and i've changed the code order of the constructor- copying the int value first, but same exception is thrown.

Comment: I've commented on the question - found the problem, it was in a generated setter for the properties.

Comment: yes, its resolved my problem, i just change null able object to non null able, and convert datetime to string directly, not by datetimeobject.value.datetime.tostring()

Comment: Great answer.  Getting an exception calling `.Value` on a null object makes sense (I guess), but the exception message is really misleading if you happen to be dealing with two Nullable objects.  Something like 'The .Value property requires the object to be non-null' would make a whole lot more sense.

Answer (score 26):

When using LINQ extension methods (e.g. `Select`, `Where`), the lambda function might be converted to SQL that might not behave identically to your C# code. For instance, C#'s short-circuit evaluated `&&` and `||` are converted to SQL's eager `AND` and `OR`. This can cause problems when you're checking for null in your lambda.

Example:

```
MyEnum? type = null;
Entities.Table.Where(a => type == null || 
    a.type == (int)type).ToArray();  // Exception: Nullable object must have a value
```

Comment: I realize this answer is not relevant to the OP's specific case, but it's relevant to the Exception he's getting. Also, this page is the first hit on Google for that exception, which makes it relevant.

Comment: This was also this issue for me with null-conditional operators ("optional chaining" in Javascript) . Instead of obj?.getValue(), I needed to do obj != null && obj.getValue()

Answer (score 8):

Try dropping the **`.value`**

```
DateTimeExtended(DateTimeExtended myNewDT)
{
   this.MyDateTime = myNewDT.MyDateTime;
   this.otherdata = myNewDT.otherdata;
}
```

Comment: doesn't help. it throws the same exception if I run the 2nd line first.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your actual question, what does "Nullable object must have a value " mean?

It is actually saying "You are trying to take the .Value of a nullable object, but it is null so that can't be done.".

I think that it is a terribly-written error message. They could have just said "Nullable object must have a value in order to take it's .Value"

Comment: I agree the exception message is terribly written. The very gist of a nullable object is that it does not have to have a value!

Answer (score 2):

Assign the members directly without the `.Value` part:

```
DateTimeExtended(DateTimeExtended myNewDT)
{
   this.MyDateTime = myNewDT.MyDateTime;
   this.otherdata = myNewDT.otherdata;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case oldDTE is null, so when you try to access oldDTE.Value the InvalidOperationException is thrown since there is no value. In your example you can simply do:

```
this.MyDateTime = newDT.MyDateTime;
```

Comment: The oldDTE is not null, but I removed the value anyhow... it is still throwing that exception....

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
`DateTimeExtended(DateTimeExtended myNewDT)
{
   this.MyDateTime = myNewDT.MyDateTime.**GetValueOrDefault();**
   this.otherdata = myNewDT.otherdata;
}`
```

It'll simply check the value and set Null if there is no value.

```
> .Value
```

Must only be used when you are sure it's coming.
But as you are not sure, you simply use ".GetValueOrDefault()"

**Explanation:**

1. `DateTimeExtended(DateTimeExtended myNewDT)` is a constructor for the `DateTimeExtended` class, which takes another `DateTimeExtended` object `myNewDT` as a parameter.
2. `this.MyDateTime = myNewDT.MyDateTime.GetValueOrDefault();` assigns
   the value of `myNewDT.MyDateTime` to the `MyDateTime` property of the current instance.`GetValueOrDefault()` is used to safely handle
   situations where `myNewDT`.`MyDateTime` might be null. If
   `myNewDT.MyDateTime` is null, this method will return the default
   value for the `DateTime` type (which is `DateTime.MinValue`).
3. `this.otherdata = myNewDT.otherdata;` assigns the `otherdata` property of the current instance with the value from myNewDT.otherdata`, assuming that other data is a non-nullable property.

**This constructor is designed to ensure that the `MyDateTime` property of the new instance is never null. It assigns a default value to `MyDateTime` if `myNewDT.MyDateTime` is null, making the code safer to use when you are not sure whether `myNewDT.MyDateTime` will have a value or not.**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like oldDTE.MyDateTime was null, so constructor tried to take it's Value - which threw.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message when trying to access values of a null valued object.

```
sName = myObj.Name;
```

this will produce error. First you should check if object not null

```
if(myObj != null)
  sName = myObj.Name;
```

This works.

Comment: Before answering, please try to read through the other answers for the question first - especially the accepted answer that states exactly what you placed in *your* answer. Though it doesn't show it using code, it spells it out. Also, try to make your example code relevant to the question's - such as `this.MyDateTime = myNewDT.MyDateTime.Value;`, not `sName = myObj.Name;`

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution and it is working for me

```
if (myNewDT.MyDateTime == null)
{
   myNewDT.MyDateTime = DateTime.Now();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception using EF Core 7.x:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

With this code:

```
Updated = new[] { x.Updated, x.Threats.Max(tac => tac.Updated) }.Max()
```

Changed `new[]` to `List<DateTime?>` and then it worked:

```
Updated = new List<DateTime?> { x.Updated, x.Threats.Max(tac => tac.Updated) }.Max()
```