# nullable object must have a value in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I use following Linq To Entitiy To get the first and only record of my 'siteconfig' Entity :

```
var site = unitofwork.SiteConfigRepository.Get().FirstOrDefault();
```

But when my application comes to the following code, throws 'nullable object must have a value' :

```
if (site!= null) { TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)site.logindDate ); }
```

And the only nullable type in my entity is a property called logindDate and is of type DateTime.

Any one help me out?

Comment: Is that the exact line where the exception is thrown? If not please expand the code and add a stack trace.

Comment: yes I put a breakpoint there, and when the application reaches that point, throws an exception.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896185/nullable-object-must-have-a-value

Comment: There is something between the `{ .... }` throwing the exception. If you are using a nullable DateTime, make sure you check for `.HasValue`.

Comment: @IAbstract  in {....} I just read and copmare loginDate in this manner : TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)site.logindDate );

Comment: @BAKeele I read the link you have suggested but I don't think it is a problem of my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (site!= null) 
{ 
    if (site.loginDate.HasValue)
    { TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract((DateTime)site.logindDate.Value ); }
}
```

You are not checking for a null `loginDate` and I suspect **that** may be the problem. Remember, when you have a nullable type, you need to check for `HasValue`, and then get the value from the `Value` property.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault() returns the first element of the enumerable, or default(T) (which is generally null, unless T is a value type) if there is no element in the list. Most probably your Get() returns an empty enumerable.

On a related matter (if indeed it is what happens), if you're sure that there is always one and only one element returned by a list, you should use Single() (because then you will have an exception thrown at that line) or test it against null *just after* the FirstOrDefault(). I think it's best having exceptions throwing or handling at the source of the unexpected behavior, and not several lines later.

Comment: that wouldn't explain the problem since OP specifically does a `null` check on `site`

Comment: I am sure that always on element returned by list, but I will use single and test the application again. [Edited] Using Single() does not work.