# asp.net core Enum Nullable object must have a value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums, nullable

I have the following `enum`:

```
public enum EventType
        {
            LoginSuccessfully = 1,
            LoginFailure = 2,
            UserCreated = 3,
            UnableToCreateUser = 4,
            PasswordReseted = 5,
            UnableToResetPassword = 6,
            UserDeleted = 7,
            UnableToDeleteUser = 8
        }
```

And I have this method:

```
public IActionResult GetFilteredLogs([FromBody] SearchFilterContract contract)
{
    //filter logs from database
}
```

Here is the `contract` received as `parameter` from my method:

```
 public class SearchFilterContract
    {
        public EventType? EventTypes { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public DateTime? fromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? toDate { get; set; }
        public int pageSize { get; set; }
        public int pageNumber {get; set;}

    }
```

If all the values from the `contract` are `Null` it gets All the values from database.

On my method I compare the variables of the contract

```
public SearchStatementSource(int? EventId,string username,DateTime? fromDate,DateTime? toDate,int pageSize, int PageNumber)

{
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendLine("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[eventslog] ");

            if(username != null)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("WHERE Username = @Username ");
            }
            else 
            {
                sb.AppendLine("WHERE Username IS NOT NULL ");
            }

            if(fromDate.HasValue)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("AND CreatedTime >= @fromDate ");
            }
            if(toDate.HasValue)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("AND CreatedTime <= @toDate ");
            }
            if(EventId.HasValue)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("AND EventId = @EventId ");
            }
            sb.AppendLine("AND Id >=" + startingIndex);
            sb.AppendLine("AND Id <=" + finalIndex);

            _command = sb.ToString();
Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@null","null"));
            AddNullable("@Username", username);
            AddNullable("@EventId", EventId);
            AddNullable("@fromDate", fromDate);
            AddNullable("@toDate",toDate);
```

The Int? EventId is the number received from the enum

Here's my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("[action]")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult GetFilteredLogs([FromBody] SearchFilterContract contract)
        {
            try
            {
                List<EventsLog> eventsLog = _logsBl.SearchLogs(contract.EventTypes,contract.Username,contract.fromDate,contract.toDate,contract.pageNumber,contract.pageSize);
                return Ok(eventsLog);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex);
            }
        }
```

And here's my DataRepository method

```
public List<EventsLog> SearchLogs(EventType? EventId, string username, DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate,int pageSize, int pageNumber)
        {
            List<EventsLog> logs = new List<EventsLog>();
            DataTable dt = Select(new SearchStatementSource((int)EventId,username,fromDate,toDate,pageSize,pageNumber));
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                logs.Add(Map(dr));
            }
            return logs;
        }
```

The exception is throwed when it calls on the Repository method the `SearchStatementSource` method

My problem here is that when I put `EventTypes` as Null it returns the following error:

"Nullable object must have a value"

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nullable object must have a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896185/nullable-object-must-have-a-value)

Comment: I don't think it's the same scenario

Comment: The error that are you saying is an Exception that is being throwed right?

Comment: Yes correct: System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check **all** the places that you use `EventTypes.Value`

That's because you're accessing the `Value` property of an null object

[See here on an Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pzRrxl)

You check it first like this:

```
if(obj.EventTypes.HasValue)
   //Do your logic
```

Or if you are using C# 6 you can use this

```
obj.EventTypes ?? DefaultValue
```

---

**Update:**

Your problem is here:

```
DataTable dt = Select(new SearchStatementSource((int)EventId, username, [...]
```

You are casting `EventId` into `int` when it can be null

Change it to `(int?)EventId`

```
DataTable dt = Select(new SearchStatementSource((int?)EventId, username, [...]
```

Comment: I have this logic inside my method:if(obj.EventTypes.HasValue)
   //Do your logic

the problem is that the exception is thrown before the method

Comment: Post your logic in the question ;)

Comment: I put the logic of the data access method

Comment: Yes, but post **relevant** logic from where the Exception is being throwed

Comment: Thanks soo much for your help!!! It worked well! I put one positive vote on that but I don't have enough reputation. Have a nice day!