# InvalidOperationException when checking if an object from an interface has a value

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I seem to be getting an unexplained System.InvalidOperationException stating that a "Nullable object must have a value" at the point when I'm checking the value of the object for null. Unfortunately I'm only receiving this randomly every 1 out of 1,000,000 messages and cant seem to replicate in my local environment with a simulator, which is why I've turned to you guys for help.

I have a foreach loop processing an array of objects:

```
ReceivedMessage[] messages = pushFeed.ReceivedMessages.GetOustandingMessages();

foreach (var m in messages)
{
    if (m != null) // only here as a sanity check to ensure m was not somehow null
    {
        if(pushFeed.Feed.ForwardReceivedMessage(m))
            logger.Info("Successfully posted to server");
        else
            logger.Warn("Failed to post to server");
    }
}
```

Inside `ForwardReceivedMessage` I'm then checking if the `Source` object within the message object is null and thats where I seem to be getting the InvalidOperationException.

```
public bool ForwardReceivedMessage(ReceivedMessage message)
{
    CommToken token;

    if (message.Source == null) // This is the line where the exception is being thrown...?
    {
        logger.Warn("Failed to forward feed with null Source...");

        return false;
    }

    // Do other things...
    return true;
}
```

The `ReceivedMessage` object is simply:

```
public class ReceivedMessage
{
    public long MessageId;
    public MessageBase Payload;
    public IAsset Source;
}
```

And the `Source` object is just an interface with the following:

```
public interface IAsset
{
    int ClientId { get; }

    ushort CommId { get; }

    int DeviceId { get; }

    short DeviceMode { get; set; }

    DateTime? LastReportTime { get; }

    string Name { get; }

    bool? Panic { get; }

    int? PassthroughDeviceId { get; set; }

    DeliveryMethod PrimaryMTDeliveryMethod { get; }

    DeliveryMethod? SecondaryMTDeliveryMethod { get; }

    // ... etc, etc
}
```

As far as I can see, the only issue can be with the `Source` object, and simply calling `message.Source` to check if it is null seems to be what is throwing the InvalidOperationException.

I'm thinking it may have something to do with `Source` being declared as the interface `IAsset` as opposed to the object, however even if `Source` were never assigned I believe I would be able to check that is has a value in an if statement?

Im hoping someone here can explain how/why this would happen, and also provide a solution to how I can check if `Source` has value or not.

Edit:
The full exception printout which I'm getting is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at CompanyName.Division.MessageHandler.Platform.PlatformHandler.ForwardReceivedMessage(ReceivedMessage message) in c:\Git\message-handler\MessageHandler\PlatformFeeds\CompanyName.Division.MessageHandler.Platform\PlatformHandler.cs:line 37
   at CompanyName.Division.MessageHandler.Core.FeedManager.<SendCallback>d__11.MoveNext() in c:\Git\message-handler\MessageHandler\CompanyName.Division.MessageHandler.Core\FeedManager.cs:line 160
```

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace to your error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896185/nullable-object-must-have-a-value

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on the `if (message.Source == null)` line. When the breakpoint is hit, please use the `Immediate Window` to check the values of each of these. Please let us know the values. If any of them throw an exception please continue to get the values of the others. a) `message` b) `message.GetType()` c) `message.Source` d) `message.Source.GetType()`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to replicate the issue on my local machine so breakpointing on that line as @mjwills suggested isn't of much help.

Comment: I have added the full exception printout as @Sefe requested

Comment: @K.Pallo In that case, consider adding logging (of those values I mention, plus the exception `StackTrace` if it occurs) on the production machine - so that when it occurs you have some extra data on hand.

Comment: @mjwills thanks for the input - will try and dump the full message in the catch block and see if that provides some further information

Comment: It is *not* a NullReferenceException.  There is a `Nullable<T>` hidden somewhere that we can't see.  Maybe your source code is outdated,  a not unlikely c:\Git problem.

Comment: @Hans Passant I do have nullable variables/objects within the `IAsset` interface which I've updated the post to reflect - but regardless of whether there is nullable variables in the object or not - why would `message.Source == null` throw an InvalidOperationException?

Comment: There is no evidence at all that IAsset is involved, it bombs inside PlatformHandler.ForwardReceivedMessage().  Interface method calls never get inlined.  You therefore have a hard fact, you know that you are not looking at the correct source code.  Get another fact by using a decompiler to look at the assembly, the Debug > Windows > Modules window shows its location.

Comment: @HansPassant Maybe I'm missing something but in the logged exception I can see `at ...PlatformHandler.cs:line 37` which is `if (message.Source == null)`. While trying to debug this I've added different validations before calling `message.Source`  and tried removing the if statement entirely - but the trace always pointed the exception to the first instance of `message.Source` in this case `if (message.Source == null)`. I also compile the solution directly on the server using the MSBuild command so I'm almost certain the if statement is whats causing the exception. Any thoughts?

Comment: As long as you can't find the `Nullable<T>` then, no, we have no hope of finding it for you.  Why you need to rely on the exception trace instead of the debugger is not obvious and a major smell.  Just don't ignore my decompiler recommendation, you don't even know yet that it is loading the correct DLL.